# Notification does not bypass Do Not Disturb mode

Tags: android

Im trying to send a notification that would bypass DND mode if the app is added to the bypass list.

My notification settings are currently this

```
setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE))
```

And I've added my app to list of apps that can bypass DND mode on my Pixel 4A and Samsung S21. The notification is showing when not in DND mode, but not showign when DND mode is enabled.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

`priority` appears to be unused here.

Try this:

```
priority = NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX
setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE))
setPriority(priority)
```

More info on the Android dev wiki: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat.Builder#setPriority(int)

Comment: Oh, my apologies, the settings are wrapped in an apply statement, so priority is being set. I will edit

Comment: Then maybe the issue is with **CATEGORY_CALL**? On my Samsung, DND mode calls and messages are treated separately from app notifications: you don't add apps to the whitelist, but contacts instead and I think that works across traditional calls as well as WhatsApp etc. Try using CATEGORY_REMINDER instead.

Comment: Weird, CATEGORY_REMINDER made them appear on my S21, but not on my 4A.. :/

Comment: Are both of your devices on the newest version of Android (13)?